# is onCreate() called upon rotation

Tags: android

For Android versions later than 2.1, is onCreate() called upon rotation? I put a log print in onCreate(), but it does not print for 2.3.3 and 4.0.3.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long free = runtime.freeMemory();
    long total = runtime.totalMemory();
    long occupied = total - free;

    Log.i("MEM", "heap: " + occupied);
}
```

On 2.1, the log message prints multiple times due to orientation; on 2.3.3, it only prints once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is always called (with the exception  being as noted above by K_Anas).  It goes through the whole process.  See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/package-summary.html), especially the configuration changes section.

And a graphic of the lifecycle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have evidence that it is not called and I'm seeking an explanation for that - either there's a problem with my experimentation or there could be cases when onCreate() is not called.

Comment: Post your code.  It is *always* called unless you tell it not to be, so the error is somewhere in your code.  Do you have an `ìf(savedinstancestate==null)` in your onCreate?  That could make it look like it is not runnig.

Comment: On my tablet with Android 5.0.1 onCreate is only called if I rotate by 90 degrees, but not if I rotate by 180 degrees.
If I set android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" only 180 degrees is possible and onCreate is never called on rotation!

Answer (score 6):

if you declared the `android:configChanges="orientation"` flag , the activity will not be destroyed and recreated (`onCreate()` will not be called) and the callback

```
onConfigurationChanged()
```

will be called.

Comment: What is the default value of android:configChanges? Does the default value change over versions (e..g, from 2.1 to 2.3.3)?

Comment: @dacongy this flag is declared on the AndroidManifest under your activity Tag, you should declare it if you want to handle orientation by your self, otherwise the system will take control of the orientation

Comment: If cases when the system takes control, will onCreate() be called?

Comment: @dacongy yes when you don't declare this flag, the system will take control and oncreate() is called

Answer (score 5):

As pointed before, if you want to avoid your activity from being recreated on rotation, thus calling onCreate() again, you must declare in your manifest corresponding configChanges.

In this case you'll have to set in your configChanges the rotation flag.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

But, starting from Android 3.0 and above you have to declare also the screenSize value.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html:

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

So, now your configChanges will look:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: In fact, that is not what I want. I was expecting onCreate() to be called multiple times, while it is not. I'm trying to figure out why it behaves NOT as expected.