# TableRow Text View content wrong after screen rotate on Android

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout within a Fragment, and I generate the rows once the fragment is created via the following Code (simplified for testing) :

```
public void displayChar(String ClassID) {
    Character charac = new Character(Integer.parseInt(ClassID), getActivity());
    TableLayout stanceListTable = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.charStanceList);
    stanceListTable.removeAllViews();
    i=0;
    for (Character.StanceCondition stanceCondition : stanceList) {
        TableRow row=createTableRow(stanceCondition);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stances)).setText(Integer.toString(i));
        Log.i("RowContent",((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stances)).getText().toString());
        stanceListTable.addView(row);
        i++;
    }
}
```

At the first creation of my activity (which only contains this fragment)
I have the good output :
[image]
But after the rotation :
[image]

But the worst part is that the Log is correct !

Before

```
08-02 12:30:37.446    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 0
08-02 12:30:37.449    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 1
08-02 12:30:37.466    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 2
08-02 12:30:37.469    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 3
```

After

```
08-02 12:30:45.653    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 0
08-02 12:30:45.656    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 1
08-02 12:30:45.660    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 2
08-02 12:30:45.662    5697-5697/com.lectem.gecharacters I/RowContent﹕ 3
```

The createTableRow method :

```
public TableRow createTableRow(Character.StanceCondition stanceCondition) {
    TableRow row =(TableRow) ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.stance_list_row,null);
    TextView hands=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stanceHands);
    hands.setText(stanceCondition.RHand + stanceCondition.LHand);

    TextView stancesView =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stances);

    MovementMethod movementMethod = stancesView.getMovementMethod();
    if ((movementMethod == null) || !(movementMethod instanceof LinkMovementMethod))
    {
        stancesView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
    Log.i("row","creating row");
    SpannableString finalss=new SpannableString("");
    /*Should be creating my spannable string here with links, but I simplified the code and changed the text after creation of the row*/
    stancesView.setText(finalss);
    return row;
}
```

Why would it display the wrong text while the getText method returns the good content... And the first TextView has the good text.
This is truly driving me crazy, what is the problem ?

EDIT : 
This is the onCreate function of my activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_char_details);
    ClassID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ClassID");
    mDetailsFragment = (CharDetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.charDetails);
    mDetailsFragment.displayChar(ClassID);

}
```

And for my fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_char_details, container, false);

}
```

EDIT 2 :

The problem seems to come from

```
    MovementMethod movementMethod = stancesView.getMovementMethod();
    if ((movementMethod == null) || !(movementMethod instanceof LinkMovementMethod))
    {
        stancesView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
```

Any idea on how I could fix it ?

Comment: I think the problem you're describing is not happening in the code you posted because I don't see any errors which could make this king of mistake. How do you handle the rotation ? Do you use something to save to state of the different objects ? Is there something that you're calling between this code and the moment when this view is returned to the user ?

Comment: I added my onCreate methods, but I doubt it will help..

Comment: the movementMethod seems to be the origin of the problem

Comment: What is the behaviour when you start the app in landscape mode and rotate to portrait mode? (ie opposite to what you'd normally do). Also what does it does when you rotate it, then rotate back, then rotate again?

Comment: It works fine when starting the app in any mode, and only have this behavior after the rotation...

Comment: It seems the same problem happens when the activity is recreated after being in background for too long

Comment: Might help you in your debugging to know that when the screen is rotated, onCreate() gets called again. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286891/is-oncreate-called-upon-rotation This is why I was wondering what happens when you rotate multiple times? Do the values stay at 3333 or does something get added to it again each time? Sounds like something is being called multiple times because onCreate is called multiple times and messing stuff up.

Comment: I already checked this, and the logs sent by my methods are fine, only the display is wrong, and it is because of the linkmovementmethod. Without the linkmovementmethod everything works fine

Comment: Update with `stanceMovementMethod` *setter*, *getter* and perhaps  `LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` methods.

Comment: Those methods all come from the standard sdk, stancesView is a TextView and LinkMovementMethod is from android library too

Comment: When you say that the problem seems to come from that specific part, do you mean you are sure? Did the problem go away when you removed that part(which seems pretty much useless).

Comment: Yes it comes from this, and as explained I simplified the exemple, I need it so that my links in the text work ( SpannableString with callback links ). The SO app seems to have the same issue for the comments. Might come from my device ?

Comment: Can you try passing the value `i` to `createTableRow`, call `setText` first and then `setMovementMethod` on `stancesView`.

Comment: I tried it too, same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an "anwser" to my problem, though if someone can explain precisely why it works, I will give accept his answer.

I simply call the displayChar method via the onStart method of the fragment. It seems that when onClose is called, LinkMovementMethod will bug. So regenerating the TextViews with OnStart seems to work.

Comment: As explained, you need to regenerate the view via the onStart method

Comment: I don't know what you mean to regenerate the view onStart.

Answer (score 0):

try **android:freezesText="true"** on your **textview** in xml, this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your `TextView's` in each row have the same id. So when saved instance state for every row is saved it overrides saved state from previous row and at the end the state of the last row is saved. Then when state is restored it populates all views with id `R.id.stances` with value of last row.

Comment: Then why does it work without the LinkMovementMethod?

Comment: MovementMethod is not added in saved instance state. But when state is restored `setText` is called on `TextView` which sets `LinkMovementMethod` necessary. [See](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3762)

Comment: I still don't understand, since when I checked the text via getText, it's the good one. Only the display was wrong.